# How to enable SLI on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg, lenovo

I have a Lenovo Y510p Laptop with two gt755m graphics cards. I installed Ubuntu updated everything and installed the nvidia drivers. When i want to enable the SLI config in /etc/X11/xorg.conf then the screen just stays black. On startup the Ubuntu Logo shows up and then the screen turns com pletly black. When i boot Ubuntu in recovery mode and empty the xorg.conf file, Ubuntu boots up normally with nvidia drivers, but no SLI.

Does anybody know how to fix that?